# Login with htaccess + welcome message with php

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a htaccess and htpasswd file.
I want that if e.g.: user1 logs in give a message that Welcome 'user1'!

My main problem is that I don't know how to tell to the php file that user1 is logged in ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can access the logged in user with this:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
```

It's been a while since I last used it though

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
{
    echo "Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}!";
}
```